# sending array from php to jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

how do i pass an array from php to jquery
both are in same file , i just have an array named $array2 with data that will be used to make graph 
below code is using chartdata but i want to use variable from my php script

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var chart;

var chartData = [{
    student: 5,
    marks: 0},
{
    student: 8,
    marks: 50},
{
    student: 10,
    marks: 100}];


AmCharts.ready(function() {
    // SERIAL CHART
    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.categoryField = "marks";
    chart.startDuration = 1;

    // AXES
    // category
    var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
    categoryAxis.labelRotation = 90;
    categoryAxis.gridPosition = "student";

    // value
    // in case you don't want to change default settings of value axis,
    // you don't need to create it, as one value axis is created automatically.
    // GRAPH
    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.valueField = "student";
    graph.balloonText = "[[category]]: [[value]]";
    graph.type = "column";

    graph.lineAlpha = 0;
    graph.fillAlphas = 8.4;
    chart.addGraph(graph);

    chart.write("chartdiv");
});
 </script>
```

Comment: Check this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use json data to pass php to jquery.

in php

```
$php_data = json_encode($your_php_data_in_array);
```

assigning to jquery

```
var data = <?php echo $php_data ;?>
```

getting the value in jquery

```
var chart_data_arr = json_decode(data);
```

now you have the data in array in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (and not necessarily the most scure/efficient/modular/blah blah)  possible way you can just dump it using json_encode

```
var chartData = [{
    student: 5,
    marks: 0},
{
    student: 8,
    marks: 50},
{
    student: 10,
    marks: 100}];

//Instead
var chartData=<?php echo json_encode($chartdata)?>
```

Alternately, you would pass it using a json action that will render the json at a certian link and use jquery to query this url and then generate the chart with that data.

Comment: quite didnt get ur alternate solution
can u explain a bit more

Comment: ajax. hyou have a script chartdata.php which does the echoing of the json encoded data. then you make an ajax call to chartdata.php and get the data in a variable $.get("chartdata.php", function(){generateChart(data),"json"}

Answer (score 0):

To use php data in javascript use:-

```
var javascriptVariable = <?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?>;
```

So javascriptVariable would become an object/array as per your php data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php 

  $your_php_array = array(.....);
?>
var chartData = <?php json_encode($your_php_array)?>;
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php